# Magento 2: Argument 1 passed to Controller::__construct() must be an instance of ..\..\..\Action\Context, instance of ..\..\..\ObjectManager given

Tags: php, dependency-injection, magento2

I am getting the following error when I try to run my Magento 2 module:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyModule\Service\Controller\Module\Version::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in
>   /srv/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93 and defined in
>   /srv/www/app/code/MyModule/Service/Controller/Module/version.php:16

This happens after I compile running this command:

```
magento setup:di:compile
```

I've read a lot of posts that suggest clearing out the /var/di and /var/generation folders and while that fixes the error, that only works in a development environment.  I cannot clear those folders in a production environment as it will cause the other extensions to break.

This is my Controller:

```
namespace MyModule\Service\Controller\Module;

class Version extends \MyModule\Service\Controller\Module {

    protected $resultJsonFactory;
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $helper = null;
    protected $config = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
     * @param \MyModule\Service\Helper\Data $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \MyModule\Service\Helper\Data $helper
    ) {

        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();
        parent::__construct($context);
        parent::initParams();

    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $data = new \stdClass();
        $data->magentoVersion = (string) $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\ProductMetadata')->getVersion();
        $data->phpVersion = (string) phpversion();
        $data->moduleEnabled = $this->helper->getConfig()['enabled'];
        $data->apiVersion = "2.0";
        return $result->setData($data);
    }
}
```

And this is what I have for MyModule\Service\Controller

```
namespace MyModule\Service\Controller;

abstract class Module extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $pageSize = null;
    protected $pageNum = 0;
    protected $startDate = null;
    protected $endDate = null;
    protected $sortDir = 'asc';
    protected $filterField = 'created_at';
    protected $id = null;
    protected $helper;

    protected function initParams() {
        if ((bool) $pageSize = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_size')) {
            $this->pageSize = $pageSize;
        }
        if ((bool) $pageNum = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page_num')) {
            $this->pageNum = $pageNum;
        }
        if ((bool) $startDate = $this->getRequest()->getParam('start_date')) {
            $this->startDate = $startDate;
            if ((bool) $endDate = $this->getRequest()->getParam('end_date')) {
                $this->endDate = $endDate;
            } else {
                $this->endDate = date('Y-m-d');
            }
        } elseif ((bool) $updatedStartDate = $this->getRequest()->getParam('updated_start_date')) {
            $this->filterField = 'updated_at';
            $this->startDate = $updatedStartDate;
            if ((bool) $updatedEndDate = $this->getRequest()->getParam('updated_end_date')) {
                $this->endDate = $updatedEndDate;
            } else {
                $this->endDate = date('Y-m-d');
            }
        }
        if ((bool) $sortDir = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sort_dir')) {
            $this->sortDir = $sortDir;
        }
        if ((bool) $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
            $this->id = $id;
        }
    }

    protected function isEnabled() {
        return $this->helper->getConfig()['enabled'];
    }

    protected function isAuthorized() {

        $token = $this->helper->getConfig()['security_token'];
        $authToken = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_TOKEN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_TOKEN'] : $_SERVER['X_TOKEN']);

        if (empty($authToken)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (trim($token) != trim($authToken)) {
            $this->helper->log('feed request with invalid security token');
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have asked a similar question myself here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/144118/24432 but so far I don't have a solution. If you find one, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in production mode, change to maintenance mode, clear var/cache,var/generation and re-run compile.
And don't forgot disable maintenance mode

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove an old generated files using rm -rf var/generation/* command from the magento root directory, because magento pre-generates all class files with their constructors. Generated classes extends the original classes and used by magento to call a plugins.